# Behind uneven (embossed/patterned) glass look - effect

Tags: photoshop-effects, effects, distort

Does anyone have idea how to approach creating same/similar effect like this one: *Lamp behind the glass*:

[image: Lamp behind the glass]

Ideally in PS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Photoshop filter, open **Filter Gallery > Distort > Glass**, change the texture option to Blocks. Play with it until you get the result you want.

[image]